# Laravel morph ANY model to user model

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relation

I have task to add starred items to the user. The items can be (Sample, Publication, Message, atc..). All items are Eloquent models that have own table like `samples`, `publications`, `messages` with primary key `id`.

I wanna do associate these models to the user as an starred items through one table (user_starrable). Structure of this table can be something like

```
id - integer
user_id - integer

model_id - integer (value like 1)
model_type - string (value like \App\Models\Sample)
```

I am trying to do this several days through morph relation, but unsuccessfully. I cannot write right methods on models to achieve this work. At the end, I need to query all models in one collection by code like `$user->starrables()->get()` and there I want to have all models together (samples, publications and messages, if relations exists). Thank you!

Models:

User.php

```
class User
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function starred() { // that i cant write
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Sample.php

```
class Sample
{
    protected $table = 'samples';

    public function starrable() {
        return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'starred');
    }
}
```

Publication.php

```
class Publication
{
    protected $table = 'publications';

    public function starrable() {
        return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'starred');
    }
}
```

Message.php

```
class Message
{
    protected $table = 'messages';

    public function starrable() {
        return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'starred');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the following models `user`, `samples`, `publications`, `messages`

Comment: @AngadDubey Done, check edits.

Comment: You need to define the `morphTo` method in the model that has the model_id, model_type columns : `user_starrable`, `UserStarrable`